# How to chroot nginx virtual hosts

Tags: linux, nginx, chroot

I want to prevent php scripts inside virtual hosts from accessing files outside their document root.

How is this possible without using containerization ?

Comment: Why not use containerization?

Comment: I have many virtual hosts , I don't want to spawn mutiple server instances, that cannot be shared with other virtual hosts.